# Is this probabilistic proof correct?

Tags: probability, number-theory, proof-verification

So I was watching the new movie *X+Y*, and there was a question therein that intrigued me:
If each integer is either green, orange or blue, then there exists integers $a,b,c$ such that $a + b$,$b+c$, and $a + c$ are all the same colour.

This seemed to invite a probabilistic proof, and so I endeavored to quickly write one:
There are infinitely many pairs of integers, and since every integer can be represented as the sum of two integers, if you randomly select two integers and sum them, there's a non-zero probability $p$ such that the sum of those two integers are a specific number, or rather a number within a specific group of numbers.

Now assuming that the three sums $a+b$, $b+c$ and $a+c$ are *independent*(this is the part I'm least sure of, and I would request that somebody please explain to me why this is formally incorrect or correct.), the probability that all three of the sums are the same colour is $p^3$. Since $p \neq 0$, $p^3 \neq 0$. Therefore since there are an infinite amount of integer triples, and a non-zero probability, there exists integers $a,b,c$ such that $a + b$,$b+c$, and $a + c$ are all the same colour.

Is this proof correct? If not, please explain why, and give an actual proof. If it is, could you give me an example of a different way to prove this.

Comment: You should probably say that $a, b, c$ must be unique or else $a=b=c$ is a very trivial solution.

Comment: Since there's infinitely many even numbers, three of them must be of the same colour, denote them $d, e, f$. Set $a = (d+e-f)/2, b = (d+f-e)/2, c = (e+f-d)/2$. Then $a+b=d, b+c=f, a+c = e$.

Comment: @Litho: Although the question didn't specify that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are positive, or even non-zero, or distinct, we can have all of this with your method, because it only needs 7 even numbers. For example, among the seven numbers {100,102,104,106,108,110,112}, we see that at least three of them must be the same color. (Because otherwise, if each of the 3 colors is used for at most 2 numbers, then we could color at most 6 numbers.)  Using your formulas for this example, we then get $a$, $b$, and $c$ as distinct integers in the range [45,61].